# Is there an efficient way of killing Lucas in Resident Evil 7 Not a Hero?

Tags: xbox-one, resident-evil-7

In the Resident Evil 7 DLC 'Not a Hero', is there an easy way to kill Lucas at the end? I'm at the last boss on professional difficulty and my items aren't really the best -- even after looting the room before the battle. My inventory isn't the best, and I was wondering if there was a really quick easy way to get it over with. Figured I would check here before going way back to an old save just in case I'm missing something. Cheers!

Comment: Are you on console or PC?

Comment: I play on Xbox one.